# In Javascript , what does the "()" at the end of the code mean?

Tags: javascript, function

Recently I have been learning JavaScript programming. I got some trouble while dealing with a JavaScript module (based on functions, which are the only things in JavaScript that create a new scope).

1.

```js
var getter = function() {
  var dayNames = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday",
    "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"
  ];
  return function(number) {
    return dayNames[number];
  };
};
console.log(getter(2));
```

2.

```js
var getter = function() {
  var dayNames = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday",
    "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"
  ];
  return function(number) {
    return dayNames[number];
  };
}();
console.log(getter(2));
```

I'm quite confused about the different result caused by the omission of the `()` parentheses.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Closing parentheses denote an [**Immediately-Invoked Function Expression**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) (or IIFE).

Comment: Although many might say this is pedantic, `()` are called "parentheses", whereas `{}` are called "braces". This established convention makes communication about the syntactical elements easier. <-- added prior to edits.

Comment: Thank you all !!!!

Answer (score 0):

I understand your confusion.  The first two general cases you see are probably relatively clear-- `()` at the end of `function` defines a function that takes no parameters (same for a named function like `function myFunction()`.  And then it is used to call functions with no parameters as well, such as in:

```
function myFunction() { // Defines the function named myFunction
    console.log('hello world');
}
myFunction(); // calls myFunction, and will console log 'hello world')
```

The extra case that is confusing is the [Immediately Invoked Function Expression (IIFE)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE).  This is when we define a function and then *immediately invoke it*.  This can be useful for a few reason-- often for purposes of creating closures:

```js
var counterizer = (function () {
 var count = 0;
 return {
  incrementCount: function () {
   count++;
   console.log(count);
  }
 }
})(); // the inner anonymous function is immediately invoked

counterizer.incrementCount();
counterizer.incrementCount();
```

Here the inner anonymous function is immediately invoked and returns an object that increments `count` and console logs it-- it is stored in a closure, and inaccessible to the outside world.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

your function return a function which means the `()` must be added if it just return number or string you doesnt have to add `()` for example

```js
//this function just return function getter()(number)
var getter = function() {
 var dayNames = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday",
"Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"
 ];
 //this one return function(number)
 return function(number) {
  return dayNames[number];
 };
};
//so if you want function to return function you must add () after that function like this:

console.log(getter()(2))
```